# Value of variable changing when passing it to another function by reference

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

I have a project in which I have to make a basic database in C. My problem lies that  keep passing a variable `n` from function to function and at one point the value changes.

I have made a test program which illustrates the same issue I'm having:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void functionTWO(int *n)
{
    printf("\n%d",*n);
}

functionONE(int *n)
{
    int i=0;
    i++;
    i++;

    *n  = i;
    printf("\n%d", *n);

    functionTWO(&n);
}

int main()
{
    int n=0;


    printf("%d",n);

    functionONE(&n);

    return 0;
}
```

The `n` in the second function is displayed as a very very high number, e.g.:

```
0
2
2752268
```

Now, I know this probably is intended, but could you guys kindly explain why this happens this way?

Comment: In [tag:c] you can't pass variables by reference. You need to read about pointers.

Comment: You are "passing `n` by reference", but didn't you mean to "pass `*n` by reference"?. `*n` and `n` are different things. (Quote marks because you are not actually passing anything by reference, and indeed you can't pass things by reference in C)

Answer (score 3):

In your `functionONE()`, `n` is already a pointer. You don't need to pass the *address* of the pointer if you intend to change that value-at-the-address.

As an advice, always check the data types and enable the compiler warnings to help you.

Comment: If i intend however to change the value in functionTWO, what would be the process? I won't need to pass the adress still?

Comment: @CodreanuGeorge See, `n` is a  pointer already, so you can simply pass `n` itself to the second function. It will work.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have an question for the author's code. for `functionTWO(&n);`, i think it shuld call `functionTWO(int**);`, because the type of `&n` is `int**`, but why it call ` void functionTWO(int *n)`?

Comment: @BlackMamba That's the irony. Compiler warnings are your friend. :)

Answer (score 2):

**functionONE()**
your are passing a address of address. So it's printing address of n.

Now you want a correct output then n as double pointer **n.

```
void functionTWO(int **n)
{
   printf("\n%d",**n);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in C `int & n` is not the reference of n, it is it's address.Now, what you've done is created an int - sent it's address to functionONE - did something to the value in that address and then sent the the argument's address to functionTWO, instead of sending the argument itself, becuase it's already a pointer. Do this instead:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void functionTWO(int *n)
    {
      printf("\n%d",*n);
    }

    functionONE(int *n)
    {
      int i=0;
      i++;
      i++;
      *n  = i;
      printf("\n%d", *n);
      functionTWO(n);      // <-- send the pointer, not it's address
    }

    int main()
    {
      int n=0;
      printf("%d",n);
      functionONE(&n);
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `functionONE`, `n` is `int *`, just a pointer, when you do `functionTWO(&n);`, you get the address of `n`, so it output a big value.

Answer (score 0):

The value being printed in `functionTWO` function is the address of the pointer variable `n` declared in `functionONE`.In that case you can either modify `functionTWO` like this

```
    void functionTWO(int **n)
    {
    printf("\n%d",**n);
    }
```

or

Just pass the value of the pointer variable like this

`functionTWO(n);`